# Clicking on voted candidate does nothing on election page

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, election

On the moderator election page, [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11), the name of the candidate you have voted  for is clickable (according to the cursor type as hand), but clicking it does nothing at all.

> [image: Click does nothing]

Clicking on the "i" icon, as expected, scrolls the page to the candidate nomination statement.

Comment: The purpose of clicking on it is to drag it to some other position but if you've only put one candidate in there you can't drag it about much.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can't drag much on an archived election page, though. Doesn't make sense to style the mouse cursor as if one can.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog can't stop me wondering what would happen if there were two candidates in the list though. Would you be able to reorder them and could we get a moderator replaced with the runner up that way?